# Meteor SimpleSchema with user dropdown

Tags: meteor

I have an app in Meteor and the idea is that an admin user can add a document and assign it to one of its customers (customers are stored in the user collection). So I would like to present a dropdownbox with customers on the document insert view. The relevant code of the schema is below:

```
customer: {
    type: [String],
    label: "Customers",
    allowedValues: function () {
      return Meteor.users.find().map(function (user) {
        return user._id
      });
    },
    autoform: {
      options: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find({}).map(function(user) {
          return {
            value: user._id,
            label: user.profile.name
          }
        })
    }
  },
    optional: true
  }
```

When I put a type: String (instead of [String]) it shows the current user only in a dropdownbox. If I use [String] (as it should be), the dropdownbox actually turns in a text box (it does not have the typical dropdown behaviour) with 3 fields (for all the users it found), yet it only shows the first one again but leaves placeholders for the other 2.

The view uses:

```
{{> afQuickField name='customer'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**: The account package, by default doest not publish the users collection. You will have to write a new publication method in your server and corresponding subscription in your client for this to work.

No read on..

Well.. This is a bit tricky. Look at the code below and edit your 'autoform' section accordingly.

```
             autoform: {
             options: function () {
            var options = [];
            Meteor.users.find().forEach(function (element) {
                options.push({
                    label: element.profile.name, value: element._id
                })
            });
            return options;
            }

          }
```

the required syntax for selection box 'options' is:

options:{[label,value],...}

The above code reads all the rows from the user collection, and pushes each row to an array called 'options' as an array.

Hope this helps or gives you some insights.

Please note that the above only works if your collection subscription/publication are proper.

Look at the following code to get a simple idea.

```
          if (Meteor.isClient) {
            Meteor.subscribe('allUsers')
           }


       if (Meteor.isServer) {
         Meteor.publish('allUsers', function() {
           return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{username:1,emails:1}})
         })
        }
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for you answer. I totally understand the reason to use a forEach. However, I think the issue is related to the fact that my Document collection only sees one uses. To test that I have put console.log(Meteor.users.find().count()) at the beginning of the Document collection and it always returns this '1' (user). How can my Document collection see all users instead of the logged in user only? The server side sees the 3 users, the client side sees 1 users and as my dropdown box is client side, it only detects 1 users.

Comment: Can you see if your subscription method is properly set?

Comment: The reason why it was not working is that by default the accounts package is only publishing the current user and indeed I needed to explicitly setup a subscription, sth I did in the relevant route. So know it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: I assumed that your subscription and publication stuff were correct. If it is working for you now, just vote the answer up, so that it becomes helpful to others in the community. Cheers !!